# bindings in wsdl

Tags: wsdl

According to http://www.w3schools.com/WSDL/wsdl_documents.asp  binding means communication protocol used by a web-service.

I know of soap can someone please mention a few other communication protocols used in web-services to pass data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP GET/POST and MIME are some alternatives [specified by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl), from the abstract:

> WSDL is extensible to allow description of endpoints and their messages regardless of what message formats or network protocols are used to communicate, however, the only bindings described in this document describe how to use WSDL in conjunction with SOAP 1.1, HTTP GET/POST, and MIME.